# InDesign to Photoshop Process

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have this Script to distribute objects to its own layers.

```
var mySels = app.selection.length;
if (mySels == 0) {
    alert("Select the object and Run the script");
    exit(0)
} else {
    while (mySels--) {
        var objLayer = app.activeDocument.layers.add();
        app.selection[mySels].itemLayer = objLayer;
    }
}
```

My question is how to make this script to select all the objects automatically, so I can run this on a folder of bunch of InDesign files?

Comment: What does this have to do with Photoshop? I see no mention of anything that’s not InDesign in the question…

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to select anything at all. Yes: scripts can work with a selection, but if you want to move *everything*, then you don't need to tell a script what that 'everything' is.

So you can loop over all [page items](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#PageItem.html) and move them to a new layer. This will fail on grouped objects, though: the group itself is one object, but all of its constituent parts are *also* listed as separate page items. The trick, then, is to check if an object's parent is 'group'.

```
doc = app.activeDocument;
for (obj=0; obj<doc.allPageItems.length; obj++)
{
    if (doc.allPageItems[obj].parent instanceof Group)
        continue;
    var objLayer = doc.layers.add();
    doc.allPageItems[obj].itemLayer = objLayer;
}
```

Before (left)/After (right) shows everything in the same layer at the left, and moved to separate layers at the right. Note how the 3 grouped lines are moved as a single object.

[image: before and after distributing over layers]

(Oh alright, to select all page items add `app.select(app.activeDocument.allPageItems);` at the start of your current script, and then it will work as well. But mine is the better way.)